Как на C++ сделать фото с вебкамеры и сохранить его
Нужно сделать фото с вебкамеры и сохранить его

Это констатация факта, а не вопрос :) Предсказываю, что ответа на вопрос в такой форме вы не получите...

Как повезёт. Всё зависит - увидит ли кто-то в этот момент (как я) и будет ли время, желание, настроение. Вам повезло. Фортуна, послала вам - меня.

#pragma comment(lib,"vfw32.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <vfw.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    char svName[256];
    char svComment[512];    
    char svBuff[1024];
    int nDriverIndex = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        if (capGetDriverDescription(nDriverIndex,
            svName,255,svComment,512)) {
            wsprintf(svBuff,
                "%d: %s %s",
                nDriverIndex,svName,svComment);
            ++nDriverIndex;
        }
    }
    if (nDriverIndex)
        wsprintf(svBuff,"%d devices listed",nDriverIndex);
    else {
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,
            "Missing video device.","Error",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    --nDriverIndex;

    WNDCLASSEX wcex={sizeof(WNDCLASSEX),0,DefWindowProc,0,0,hInstance,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"wndname",NULL,};
    ATOM Atom=RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    if(!Atom) {
        Atom=RegisterClass((LPWNDCLASS)&wcex.style);
        if (!Atom) {
            MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,
                "Failed register class.","Error",
                MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
            ExitProcess(0);
        }
    }
    HWND hWnd=CreateWindowEx(0,MAKEINTATOM(Atom),"appname",0,0,0,0,0,HWND_DESKTOP,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
    if (!hWnd) {
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,
            "Failed register class.","Error",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    HWND hwndCap=capCreateCaptureWindow("wnd_cap_frame",
        WS_CHILD,0,0,160,120,hWnd,1);
    if (!hwndCap) {
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,
            "Failed create cap window.","Error",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    if (!capDriverConnect(hwndCap,nDriverIndex))
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwndCap);
        wsprintf(svBuff,
            "Failed connect to driver #%d",
            nDriverIndex);
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,
            svBuff,"Error",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    CAPDRIVERCAPS pcdc;
    capDriverGetCaps(hwndCap,&pcdc,sizeof(CAPDRIVERCAPS));
    if (!pcdc.fCaptureInitialized)
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwndCap);
        wsprintf(svBuff,"Failed init driver #%d",nDriverIndex);
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,
            svBuff,"Error",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    DWORD dwSize=capGetVideoFormatSize(hwndCap);
    BITMAPINFO* pbiOrig=(BITMAPINFO*)malloc(dwSize);
    if (!pbiOrig)
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwndCap);
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,
            "Failed allocate memory.","Error",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    BITMAPINFO* pbiInfo=(BITMAPINFO*)malloc(dwSize);
    if (!pbiInfo) {
        DestroyWindow(hwndCap);
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,
            "Failed allocate memory #2","Error",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    capGetVideoFormat(hwndCap,pbiOrig,dwSize); 
    memcpy(pbiInfo,pbiOrig,dwSize);
    pbiInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth = 640;
    pbiInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight = 480;
    pbiInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 16;
    pbiInfo->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    pbiInfo->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    pbiInfo->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    pbiInfo->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    pbiInfo->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    pbiInfo->bmiColors->rgbBlue = 0;
    pbiInfo->bmiColors->rgbGreen = 0;
    pbiInfo->bmiColors->rgbRed = 0;
    pbiInfo->bmiColors->rgbReserved = 0;

    /* Set video format. */
    capSetVideoFormat(hwndCap,pbiInfo,dwSize);
    capGrabFrameNoStop(hwndCap);
    capFileSaveDIB(hwndCap,"Cap_001.bmp");

    /* Restore original format. */
    capSetVideoFormat(hwndCap,pbiOrig,dwSize);
    capDriverDisconnect(hwndCap);
    DestroyWindow(hwndCap);
    MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,
        "Capture frame - OK!","Info",
        MB_OK| MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
    return 0;
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Да. Нужно осуществлять сборку программы - установив в свойствах проекта, режим MBCS (мультибайтовая кодировка) или оформить значения строк с помощью макроса TEXT("Error").
